# Angles and distances for photogarametry

Tags: lens, subject-distance, 3d, focus-distance

I want to photoshoot rocks which are about 20cm by 20cm by 20cm and make a 3D model of it. I am yet to find the software to create the 3D model but might use VisualSFM. Question is what angles, distances and lenses are recommended for these dimensions?

There are many rocks I will need to photo so using the minimum required photos would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most any camera and lens combination will work. Because your subjects are a 20cm (8 inches) in size, likely you will need to work in close. Most modern cameras have a close-up mode so you will be OK. For optimum results when making close-up shots, choose a macro lens. These are lenses are optimized for close in work. To make a 3D image of an object, you can use an ordinary still camera. Just take two pictures, each with a slightly different viewpoint. To accomplish, we take a shot and then shift the camera and take a second shot. The spacing between the two images, called parallax spacing, is about the same as the distance between our two eyes (pupillary distance). This is about 65mm ( 2 ½ inches). You can experiment, increasing accentuates the illusion of 3D.

You might procure a aid that mounts to a tripod, slowing you to shift between shots with accuracy. You can also build such a parallax shifter. Best of luck.